# If method A calls method B, should you test method B before testing method A in junit?

Tags: java, unit-testing

**If method A calls method B, should you test method B before testing method A in JUnit?**

I think method A is the answer since method B depends on method A. What are your thoughts?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "before"? I mean, testing both seems like a good idea, but why would there be a temporal relationship between the tests?

Comment: I don’t understand the question. Are you talking about the order you write the tests?

Comment: JUnit does not (last time I checked) allow you to specify the order of test execution in such detail. If you need to create such an order then consider using (the very similar but more powerful) NG Test instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, Java or any language doesn't matter in this question.

I would answer to your question by "it depends on".

From a dependency point of view, the `A` method depends on the `B` method so yes `B` should exist and be tested before `A`.
But now according to the development methodology used, you will test first which brings value in terms of business/risks/features, and so for.
For example this is the case for methodologies as `RUP` and `XP`.

And so if it is required as `A` should be first implemented, the `B` part will be stubbed/faked/mocked for the moment and will be implemented in a next step or later.

Answer (score 0):

of course yes if you give to mB() all elements for it's interface...

```
public int mA(int pValue)
{
    int vValue = pValue++;
    return mB(vValue);
}
public int mB(int pValue)
{
    int vValue += pValue;
    return vValue;
}
```

you can test int mB(int) before int mA(int) keeping in mind these two functions doesn't return the same result ...